# Kendo React Charts not displayed as expected

Tags: reactjs, kendo-react-ui

I'm trying to integrate Kendo Charts into my project, but unlike other Kendo components, Charts are not displayed as expected.
What I expect:[Component on Kendo site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJvEE.png)
What I get:[Component on my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHzOK.png)
Code:
`<Chart>` 
 `<ChartSeries>`
  `<ChartSeriesItem data={[ 1, 2, 3, 5 ]} name="Fibonacci"/>`
 `</ChartSeries>`
`</Chart>`

Answer (score 1):

Seeing at the [documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/charts/get-started/). You're probably missing the styling theme.

Try installing the default theme:
`npm install --save @progress/kendo-theme-default`

and then import it in your App.jsx or App.tsx file, or in the component you have your chart.

`import '@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css';`

Or according to kendo [examples](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ztrb9y?file=index.html), you could simply add the styling in the index.html head:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/themes/4.42.0/default/default-main.css"></link>`

I prefer the first option.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, other components work well for me, I have a kendo theme, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Well sorry about that, I'm pretty sure it's the theme not being imported correctly in that specific component. Do you import it there?

Comment: I can use any kendo components on the same page, they look good, I can put a regular theme or even make my own, this does not affect the charts in any way. And yes I import theme in the App.tsx

Comment: Well if nothing works, then I suggest you create a reproducible sandbox example. It is unclear what the cause is by what you've shared.

Comment: I tried it in the sandbox and it works, but it doesn't work in my project. I tried reinstalling but nothing helps. I don't know what to do

Comment: as if the component just doesn't know that I'm importing a theme

Comment: Try importing the theme in the component again, there might be a styling interference from other components in your setup. Sorry again shooting in blind without any repro

Comment: I am having similar issues.  I did notice when I went to the sandbox they include a cdn stylesheet that is not kendo-default-themes. <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/themes/5.0.1/default/default-main.css"></link>